# In triangle given altitude and median and side , find sides of this triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In triangle $ABC$ given $BC=a$ and the altitude $BH=h_{b}=x$ and median $AM=m_{a}=y$

Then find the sides of triangle $ABC$ mean find $AB,AC$ ?

Also how we can represented ?

My try but not complete :

I know that : $m_{a}^{2}=\frac{2(b^{2}+c^{2})-a^{2})}{4}$

And I know that : $h_{b}=\frac{2S}{b}$ 
I have many relations but I can't use it ? 
I have already see your solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two equations for the altitude $x$ and the median $y$ can be established,

$$b^2+c^2=\frac{a^2}2+2y^2$$
$$\sqrt{c^2-x^2}=b-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$

Square the second equation and eliminate $c$ to get,

$$b^2-b\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac{a^2}4-y^2=0$$

Solve for the side $b$ in terms of known $a$, $x$ and $y$,

$$b= \frac12 \sqrt{a^2-x^2} +\frac12\sqrt{4y^2-x^2}$$

The side $c$ can then be obtained from $b$,

$$c= \sqrt{\frac{a^2}4+2y^2-b^2}$$
$$=\left[\frac14\left(\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-\sqrt{4y^2-x^2}\right)^2+x^2\right]^{1/2}$$

Comment: Thank you sir @Quanto , but how you two first equations ? And how we can represented without calculus sides ?

Comment: @Ellen Ellen - The first equation is for the median $y$, as you pointed out in the post. The second equation from applying the Pythagorean theorem to the two right triangles formed by the altitude BH.

Comment: can tell me where I can find it this two equation with proof ?

Comment: @Ellen Ellen - Note that b = AH + HC, where $AH^2=c^2-x^2$ and $HC^2=a^2-x^2$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry)

Comment: Ooh its OK I understand you

Comment: Thank I understand the second  , and how about first first equation ? How

Comment: @Ellen Ellen - It is the same equation you refer in your post $m_{a}^{2}=\frac{2(b^{2}+c^{2})-a^{2})}{4}$